# Pass Where and Orderby Clause using Func for Generic Method

Tags: c#, linq

I have Generic Method for Pagination and i want to pass Where clause and order by clause. Is there a way to pass both at same. Thank you

```
public TableResponse<T> GetPagination<T>(Func<T, bool> filterslambda, Filters filter) where T: class
{
 var query = db.Set<T>().Where(filterslambda).AsQueryable();
}
```

Here I m calling my generic method

```
GetPagination<Employee>(x => x.IsActive == true ,filter); <------ Here i want to pass order by after where clause is performed..
```

Comment: What is stopping you from adding another parameter and use it as the OrderBy predicate.

Comment: linq's `orderby` takes either `Func<TSource,TKey>` or `Func<TSource,TKey>` and `IComparer<TKey>`. Just pass these in.

Comment: Note, if you are using something like entity framework you likely want to pass in a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` not just a `Func<T, bool>` or else you will not actually perform the query server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there

```
public TableResponse<T> GetPagination<T,Tkey>(Func<T, bool> predicate, Func<T, Tkey> selector) 
   where T: class
{
    var query = db.Set<T>().Where(predicate).OrderBy(selector);
}
```

Comment: How would i call it?

Comment: GetPagination<Employee>(x => x.IsActive == true ,filter); how would i call orderby with id Here?

Comment: @B.Mick `GetPagination<Employee>(x => x.IsActive == true ,x => x.SomeProp);`

Comment: Using the generic method requires 2 type arguments. It gives thiz error

Comment: @B.Mick you'll have to specify the type of the property, `GetPagination<Employee,string>(x => x.IsActive == true ,x => x.SomeProp);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IOrderedQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iorderedqueryable-1?view=netframework-4.8) like below

```
public TableResponse<T> GetPagination<T>(Func<T, bool> filterslambda, Filters filter, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null) where T: class
{
  var query = db.Set<T>().Where(filterslambda).AsQueryable();
  return orderBy != null ? orderBy(query) : query;
}

GetPagination<Employee>(x => x.IsActive == true ,filter, x => x.OrderBy(x => x.Id));
```